# Sending HTTP POST Through Lightning App

Tags: rest-api, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to send an HTTP POST to a third party API in a lightning application but keep running into an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The problem lines of code are in my helper class:

```
// This first line alone throws the error
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint('https://www.google.com');
req.setHeader('Host','www.google.com');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: you are not setting endpoint in the request. Try replacing `req.setHeader('Host','www.google.com');` with `req.setEndpoint('https://www.google.com');`

Comment: The error come about even before the request is sent, lightning doesn't seem to like the first line: 'HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();'

Comment: Rob, setting the endpoint would solve the issue.I have verified it in my dev org.Also make sure the endpoint is whitelisted by adding in it Remote Site settings.

Comment: I have modified the code to set the endpoint but it is still not working. In fact, it doesn't even make it to that line of code. Did you put this in a lightning app or APEX? In APEX this isn't a problem but in lightning I can't even declare HttpRequest

Comment: I tested the above code by putting it inside an `@AuraEnabled` method which would be called by Lightning Component's doInit method.

Comment: Do you mean that you put this code inside of an APEX class and added @AuraEnabled to that class? I have read that Lightning apps are sandboxed differently than APEX. How would this setup work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44382/discussion-between-praveen-and-rob).

Comment: Yes you need to use APEX to do API Request, you cannot do API request redirectly from Lightning. Look at this [tutorial1](http://peterknolle.com/rest-api-lightning-component/) and [tutorial2](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/lightning-component-for-wikipedia-search/) it will help you out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discussed, you cannot do an API Request from Lightning Component directly at the moment.You need to it via APEX controller by calling `@AuraEnabled` method to do the job for the LC.

So there's an example I did from the code you shared in the chat:

**TestCmp.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="LightningContactController"> 
    <ui:button label="Post Comment" press="{!c.postChatterFeed}"/> 
</aura:component>
```

**TestCmpController.js**

```
({ 
    postChatterFeed : function(cmp, event, helper) { 
        helper.postChatterFeed(cmp, event, helper); 
    } 
})
```

**TestCmphelper.js**

```
({ 

    postChatterFeed : function(cmp, event, helper) { 
        var action = cmp.get("c.getPostToPusher"); 

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) { 
            var state = response.getState(); 
            if (state === "SUCCESS") { 
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue()); 
            } 
            else { 
                alert("ERROR"); 
            } 
        }); 

        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
        } 
    })
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
public class LightningContactController { 
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static String getPostToPusher() { 
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
        req.setMethod('POST'); 
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.google.com'); 
        req.setHeader('Host','www.google.com'); 

        Http http = new Http(); 
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req); 
        return 'Hello world'; 
    } 
}
```